# Center align a single cell in table

Tags: multirow

I am trying center align the cell with Overall completion time and Task 3 (problematic sections) completion time. here is my code. I need to center align only these two cells

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Pairwise comparisons for overall and task 3 (problematic sections) completion time} 
  \label{tab:taskcompletiontimepairwise}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}p{2.0cm}p{1.5cm}}
    \toprule
      Interface (i) &
      Interface (j) &
     Mean Difference (i-j) & Std. Error & Sig. \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{1}{*} {Overall completion time} \\
    \midrule 
    Traditional & Timed & 36.96  & 30.95 & .753 \\ 
    Traditional & VidComm & 105.98\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} & 29.90 & .009 \\
    Timed & VidComm & 69.03  & 34.71 & .196 \\ 
    \bottomrule
     \multirow{1}{*}{Task 3 (problematic sections) completion time} \\
    \midrule 
    Traditional & Timed & -4.03  & 18.39 & 1.000 \\ 
    Traditional & VidComm & 58.30 & 22.49 & .061 \\
    Timed & VidComm & 62.33\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} & 15.65 & .004 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textasteriskcentered] The mean difference is significant at the 0.05 level.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view the `\multirow` in that table isn't usefull. For centering over the full range of columns use `\multicolumn{5}{c}{your text}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htb]
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Pairwise comparisons for overall and task 3 (problematic sections) completion time} 
  \label{tab:taskcompletiontimepairwise}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}p{2.0cm}p{1.5cm}}
    \toprule
      Interface (i) &
      Interface (j) &
     Mean Difference (i-j) & Std. Error & Sig. \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{1}{*} {Overall completion time} \\
    \midrule 
    Traditional & Timed & 36.96  & 30.95 & .753 \\ 
    Traditional & VidComm & 105.98\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} & 29.90 & .009 \\
    Timed & VidComm & 69.03  & 34.71 & .196 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Task 3 (problematic sections) completion time} \\
%     \multirow{1}{*}{Task 3 (problematic sections) completion time} \\
    \midrule 
    Traditional & Timed & -4.03  & 18.39 & 1.000 \\ 
    Traditional & VidComm & 58.30 & 22.49 & .061 \\
    Timed & VidComm & 62.33\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} & 15.65 & .004 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textasteriskcentered] The mean difference is significant at the 0.05 level.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```